# simple arithmetic on index of foreach statement in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, foreach

Is foreach really a tikz statement or is derived from some other package?

I would like to draw a horizontal axis with 7 ticks spaced 1 cm apart.
I'd like to place a label under each tick that is the ordinal number of the tick (1,2,3..)
and a label above the tick that is the value of the ordinal number multiplied by
the constant 3.14

Answer (score 35):

Yes, `foreach` is a TikZ/PGF statement. It is described in the very detailed [`pgfmanual`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). You can also use it independently of TikZ/PGF by issuing `\usepackage{pgffor}` in your preamble. This is not necessary if you're using TikZ, as it will be loaded automatically.

Here's an example of how to achieve what you described in your question. `\pgfmathsetmacro<macroname>{<expression>}` uses the PGF math engine to do the calculation and assigns the result to a macro, while `\pgfmathprintnumber` rounds and outputs the result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {1,...,7} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\result{\x * pi}
    \draw (\x,-4pt) -- (\x,4pt)
        node [below,yshift=-2ex] {\x}
        node [above] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\result}};
}

\draw [-latex] (1,0) -- (7.6,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: axis with labels]

Comment: thanks, Jake. Is there an implicit loop index in foreach that can be referenced by the user?

Comment: You can use `/pgf/foreach/count` for that. Write something like `\foreach \x [count=\i] in {a,...,z}` and `\i` will hold the loop counter (e.g. `1` for `a`, `2` for `b` etc.).

Answer (score 26):

Two solutions using only `foreach` own computing tools

```
\foreach \x [count=\i] in {3.14,6.28,...,21.98}
```

Difference between second and first items in list is calculate and added to second and successive values until it reaches the last one. On the same time `\i` counts list items.

```
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \x using \i*3.14] in {1,2,...,7}
```

`\i` advances through the list and it's used to calculate a new variable `\x`.

Both solutions produce the same result:

[image]

The complete code could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x [count=\i] in {3.14,6.28,...,21.98} {
    \draw (\i,-4pt) -- (\i,4pt)
        node [below,yshift=-2ex] {\i}
        node [above] {\x};
}

\draw [-latex] (1,0) -- (7.6,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \x using \i*3.14] in {1,2,...,7} {
    \draw (\i,-4pt) -- (\i,4pt)
        node [below,yshift=-2ex] {\i}
        node [above] {\x};
}

\draw [-latex] (1,0) -- (7.6,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```