# How to put text inside chronoperiode timeline-bar?

Tags: colorbox, timeline, bar, chronology, chronosys

How can I put text inside the bar instead of over the bar?
Thank you in advance for your help!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{chronosys}

\begin{document}
%---------------------timeline----------------%
\startchronology[align=left, startyear=1790,stopyear=1860, height=0pt, startdate=false, stopdate=false, dateselevation=0pt, arrow=false, box=true]
%
\chronograduation[event][dateselevation=0pt]{10}
%---------------------periods----------------%
\chronoperiode[textstyle=\raggedleft\colorbox{green}, color=green, startdate=false, bottomdepth=0pt, topheight=8pt, textdepth=-15pt,dateselevation=16pt, stopdate=false]{1790}{1860}{Text}
%
\chronoperiode[textstyle=\colorbox{blue}, color=blue, startdate=false, bottomdepth=8pt, topheight=16pt, textdepth=-20pt, dateselevation=12pt, stopdate=false]{1850}{1860}{More text}
%
\stopchronology


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add not a chunk of code but a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @CecilieV  -- please see if the answer suits your requirement

Answer (score 1):

With help from --

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297685/197451

and

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18119/197451

I found it easier with just `TiKz`

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Biographical cornerstones}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0mm,
      L/.style = {% as Line style for the gray base line with length 10 units 
    draw=gray, 
    line width=1.5mm,
    {Bar[width=22mm,line width=1pt]}-{Bar[width=22mm,line width=1pt]}% for the corner 
    %ticks
                 }
                    ]
\draw[L]    ( 0,0)  coordinate (s)% draw the base bar of gray color
                    node[above=10mm] {1790} --  
            (10,0)  node[above=10mm] {1860};
            
\draw[green!40,line width=4.5mm]    %draw the next bar of green color
            ( 0.03,0.3)  coordinate (t)--
            node[pos=0.5,black] {Some text}
            (9.97,0.3) ;

\draw[blue!40,line width=4.5mm]    % draw the blue bar
            ( 6*1.43,0.72)  coordinate (r)--         % 7portions of the base bar is 
                                                      %1.43 units each i.e 10/7
            node[pos=0.5,black,font=\tiny,align=center] {More \\text}
            (9.97,0.72) ;

\foreach \x in {1,...,6}{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\result{1790+(\x * 10)}    % macro to calculate labels
\draw[gray,line width=1pt]                        %draw the ticks for each year
            (\x*1.43,0)--
            node[left,
                rotate=90,
                xshift=-1em,
                font=\tiny]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\result}}
            (\x*1.43,-0.5);}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```