# Month option in chronosys

Tags: chronosys

I'm working on a [`chronosys`](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/chronosys/docchronosys_en.pdf) timeline and I would like to specify the precise date of an event as it affects the position but I don't want it to appear on the timeline.

Is there a way to make a command to remove the month of an event the same way it is possible not to show the year with `year=false` ?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{chronosys}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} \centering

\startchronology[startyear=-100,stopyear=-30,height=2ex]
\chronoevent[textstyle=\bf,
datesstyle=\it,datesseparation=/,conversionmonth=false,
year=false, textwidth=4.5cm]{3/-44}
{\qquad ides of March;\endgraf
assassination of Caesar}
\chronoevent[textstyle=\bf,
datesstyle=\it,datesseparation=/,conversionmonth=false,
year=false,]{10/-79}
{Eruption of Mont Vesuvius}
\stopchronology

\end{figure}        
\end{document}
```

In this exemple, the result is as follow

[image]

And I would like to have something like that

[image]

Which I can achieve by not specifying `{3/-44}` but just `{-44}` (same with `{10/-79}`) but I dont want because when specifying the month the position of the ticks is more precise.

Comment: Why don't you just start your code at `\documentclass`, end it at `\end{document}` and try it to compile in an empty file in a new directory? Finally please post what compiled in the end AND shows your problem. Thank you

Comment: have alook at the answer here --https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560905/how-to-put-text-inside-chronoperiode-timeline-bar/560980#560980 -- I found it easier to frame the timeline with just `Tikz`

Comment: @MS-SPO My bad, I edited the code to have a full mwe,

Comment: Do you want to remove the month for all events in a chronology or only for specific events?

Comment: I would like to have an argument for `\chronoevent` to show or not the month of an event like `year=<option>` does for the year of the event

Comment: Unfortunately, `chronosys` is extremely difficult to customise if the package's options don't already do what you want. You really have two options. (1) Email the package author requesting a modified version. (2) Use something other than `chronosys`. [I'm writing a package which is basically a development from answers here addressing the difficulties adapting `chronosys`. Either that or a simple Ti*k*Z solution could work, but means switching from `chronosys`.]

Comment: I don't get the output you report getting when I compile your code.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely happy with this, but ...

[image: look-almost-alike with years-only events]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701307/ i gwestiwn BlueMarker: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/695378/
% https://codeberg.org/cfr/chronos
% rev. 9866
\usepackage{chronos}

\begin{document}
\begin{chronos}
  [
    simple arrow,
    timeline={
      dates={-100}:{-30},
      width=\linewidth,
      height=2ex,
      major step font=\normalfont,
      minor step font=\normalfont,
      year format={!q!Y},
      timeline marks=false,
      timeline year={yshift=30pt},
      step major year=70,
      step from year={-100},
    },
    every date format={!q!Y},
    event/.cd,
    text font=\upshape\bfseries,
    date font=\itshape,
  ]
  \chronosevent{name=eruption of Mont Vesuvius,date={{-79}-10},}
  \chronosevent{name=ides,name content={\qquad ides of March;\hfill\mbox{} assassination of Caesar},date={{-44}-3},text width=45mm}
\end{chronos}
\end{document}
```